# Automatically adjust zoom to accommodate all marker in a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using the latest version of Google maps. How to add markers using longitude and latitude and automatically adjust the zoom level of the map to include all the markers using JavaScript?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Google Maps API v3 provides a `LatLngBounds` object to which you can add multiple `LatLng` objects. You can then pass this to [`Map.fitBounds()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) function as described here:

- [Zoom-To-Fit All Markers, Polylines or Polygons on A Google Map](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2009/03/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-polylines-or.html) - API v2
- [Zoom-to-Fit All Markers on Google Map v3](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2011/03/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-map.html)

**Partial Example**

```
var latlng = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(1.23, 4.56),
    new google.maps.LatLng(7.89, 1.01),
    // ...
]; 
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
    latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
}
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

Comment: BTW: When operating on array of markers, you may get markers' position using the `getPosition()` method.

Comment: How to set precise zoom level according to place's location ? For example for California one zoom level and different zoom level for Los Angles ? Just like google map which sends zoom level according to search term in params ?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, this feature probably belongs to the Google geocoding API, I think the search results contain the place information and optimal viewport for that place, which could be a building or a city etc

Comment: See https://github.com/salmanarshad2000/demos/blob/v1.0.4/google-maps/latitude-longitude-finder-tool.html

Answer (score 26):

You add markers to your google map by instantiating a [marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) object for each of your latitude/longitude pairs:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currentLatLng, 
    map: map,
    title:"Title!"
});
```

The [map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) option on the marker constructer will associate the new market object with your map.

To zoom your map to include your new markers, you use the *fitBounds* method on the [map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) object. fitBounds takes a [latLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object as a parameter. This object has a handy *extend* method which will adjust the bounds to include a new latitude/longitude.  So you just need to spin through all your points, calling *extend* on a single latLngBounds object.  This will extend the bounds to include all your markers.  Once you have done this, you pass this object into the *fitBounds* method on the [map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) and it will zoom to show all your new markers.

Comment: although you provided the correct answer *first*.. as usual most of the points went to the other *same* answer that actually had some sample code..

Answer (score 4):

The following did the trick for me

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);


 // add a zoom to the map


var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function()
        {
          if(map.getZoom() > 16)
            map.setZoom(17);
          google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
        });
```

Set your desired zoom in the setZoom() method. The larger the value, the wider it shows location details, the smaller the value, it throttles and shrinks the location details