# How to Center/Set Zoom of Map to cover all markers visible on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am setting multiple markers to My Map

I can set statically the zoom levels and the center

but what i want is To Center to all markers and zoom level to fill all visible markers

I can use the Gmaps.MoveToRegion method which receives a MapSpan. The thing is, I don't know how to calculate the MapSpan needed to show all the markers.

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Maps and Xam.Plugin.MapExtend.Abstractions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a function called map.fitBounds() that does what you describe for javascript API and android API. Here's a [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897744/automatically-adjust-zoom-to-accomodate-all-marker-in-a-google-map) for further explanation. Not sure how you would do it in Xamarin, but hope this is a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the damn thing using an algorithm I found here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

In Xamarin is smth like this:

```
var radioTierra = 6371000; //metros
        var latitud1Radianes = pos1.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        var latitud2Radianes = pos2.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        var longitud1Radianes = pos1.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);

        var deltaLatitud = (pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude) * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        var deltaLongitud = (pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude) * (Math.PI / 180.0);


        var sumando1 = Math.Sin(deltaLatitud / 2) * Math.Sin(deltaLatitud / 2);
        var sumando2 = Math.Cos(latitud1Radianes) * Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) * Math.Sin(deltaLongitud / 2) * Math.Sin(deltaLongitud / 2);
        List<double> sumandos = new List<double>();
        sumandos.Add(sumando1);
        sumandos.Add(sumando2);
        var a = sumandos.Sum();
        var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));

        var distance = radioTierra * c;

        /* Δφ es deltaLatitud
         * Δλ es deltaLongitud*/
        var Bx = Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) * Math.Cos(deltaLongitud);
        var By = Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) * Math.Sin(deltaLongitud);
        var φ3 = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(latitud1Radianes) + Math.Sin(latitud2Radianes),
                            Math.Sqrt((Math.Cos(latitud1Radianes) + Bx) * (Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) + Bx) + By * By));//Latitud del punto medio
        var λ3 = longitud1Radianes + Math.Atan2(By, Math.Cos(longitud1Radianes) + Bx);//Longitud del punto medio

        var centro = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(φ3, λ3);
        Distance distancia = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Distance(distance + 0.2);

        Gmaps.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(centro, distancia));
```

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old post, but could you explain a bit your code please? :/

Comment: @Emixam23 It is explained here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @AbelAlejandro can you please explain a bit how above calculations will change when the number of markers are more than 2. Say 4 markers. Will Lat1, Long1 will be minimum latitude and longitude from the 4 markers.. and Lat2, Long2 the maximum latitude and longitude ?

Comment: @Vicky It wasn't meant for more than 2 markers. If I had to do it to support N markers, I would settle for the absolute maximums and minimums for both latitude and longitude since all the markers would fit between those 4 values.

Comment: @AbelAlejandro thanks.. I am trying to make it work using Max and Min Latitude and Longitude as you advised.. will update how it goes..

Comment: @AbelAlejandro its not working somehow.. the two points/markers I have are (-30.6800957738313, 116.730567836211) and (-30.6803060885055, 116.730415620849)  where first value is latitude and second value is longitude.. Somehow when I enter these values in movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, I get the correct render... but in my program MoveToRegion is moving my map to the wrong place...

Comment: @AbelAlejandro  That was because you are directly passing φ3, λ3 as Radians to Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position. We need to first convert them back to degrees as that is what Position expects. Also, could you please clarify what does 0.2 in Distance signify ? Is it to create a buffer around the markers ?

Comment: @Vicky Yes, I think that 0.2 was meant to give a bit of buffer. Please bear in mind this code was written 5 years ago for a POC and it ended up being discarded for some other code. It was never commited, used, let alone tested. I don't use Xamarin anymore and actually I'm a freelance Java developer now. Since I wrote this I moved countries twice, I got married, I learned French and Italian, I broke my knee and recovered. Actually I'm embarrased about this code and if I would have to do something similar again I would certainly not go down this same route. I hope it helps you somehow though.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add custom map render to your android project that will inherit MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter

```
    public class MyMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
```

I have added 2 private fields

```
    private GoogleMap _map;
    private LatLngBounds.Builder _builder;
```

In the constructor initialize your _builder:

```
    public MyMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    }
```

When override OnMapReady method set GoogleMap property as this:

```
    protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);

        NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        if (_map == null)
        {
            _map = map;
        }
    }
```

And you need to override CreateMarker method so you can change your zoom level

```
    protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
    {
        var p = (THHPin)pin;

        var marker = new MarkerOptions();
        LatLng position = new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude);
        marker.SetPosition(position);
        marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
        marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);

        _builder.Include(position);
        LatLngBounds bounds = _builder.Build();

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(bounds, 20);

        _map.MoveCamera(cu);
        return marker;
    }
```

Comment: This works for both iOS and Android? @Ljupcho Hristov

Comment: @KalleP yes this is in shared proj

Answer (score 1):

I had success with the below c# code. Just record the position of each marker as a LatLng object.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

criteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine;
criteria.PowerRequirement = Power.Low;

provider = locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);

location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);

marker1lat = location.Latitude;
marker1lng = location.Longitude;

marker2lat = location.Latitude;
marker2lng = location.Longitude;

LatLng marker1LatLng = new LatLng(marker1lat, marker1lng);
Latlng marker2LatLng = new LatLng(marker2lat, marker2lng);

LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .Include(marker1LatLng)
                    .Include(marker2LatLng);

mMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(b.Build(), 120));
```