# Determine the zoom level to cover all marker about lat/lng

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I know, what I ask exist with Google Map, but I'm working with **Xamarin.Forms.Map** so.. I have to make it by my own.

However, I know how to get the center of my point, the **POI (Point of Interest)**, but I don't know how to determine the zoom of the camera..

I searched on the web and **[from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248015/how-to-center-set-zoom-of-map-to-cover-all-markers-visible-on-xamarin-forms)**, I got redirected to the algorythm of **[Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)**.

However, I tried the code given but it doesn't work.. I know how to find the POI, the 2 farest point, but I can't determine the zoom..

Any idea please? :/

**Note:** There is the code if you want to know something about what I tried

```
    #region Camera focus method
    private static void OnCustomPinsPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        CustomMap customMap = ((CustomMap)bindable);

        if (customMap.CameraFocusParameter == CameraFocusReference.OnPins)
        {
            List<Position> PositionPins = new List<Position>();
            bool onlyOnePointPresent;

            foreach (CustomPin pin in (newValue as List<CustomPin>))
            {
                PositionPins.Add(pin.Position);
            }
            Position CentralPosition = GetCentralPosition(PositionPins);
            if (PositionPins.Count > 1)
            {
                Position[] FarestPoints = GetTwoFarestPointsOfCenterPointReference(PositionPins, CentralPosition);
                customMap.CameraFocus = GetPositionAndZoomLevelForCameraAboutPositions(FarestPoints);
                onlyOnePointPresent = false;
            }
            else
            {
                customMap.CameraFocus = new CameraFocusData() { Position = CentralPosition };
                onlyOnePointPresent = true;
            }
            customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(customMap.CameraFocus.Position,
            (!onlyOnePointPresent) ? (customMap.CameraFocus.Distance) : (new Distance(5))));
        }
    }
    public static Position GetCentralPosition(List<Position> positions)
    {
        if (positions.Count == 1)
        {
            foreach (Position pos in positions)
            {
                return (pos);
            }
        }

        double lat = 0;
        double lng = 0;

        foreach (var pos in positions)
        {
            lat += pos.Latitude;
            lng += pos.Longitude;
        }

        var total = positions.Count;

        lat = lat / total;
        lng = lng / total;

        return new Position(lat, lng);
    }
    public class DataCalc
    {
        public Position Pos { get; set; }
        public double Distance { get; set; }
    }
    public static Position[] GetTwoFarestPointsOfCenterPointReference(List<Position> farestPosition, Position centerPosition)
    {
        Position[] FarestPos = new Position[2];
        List<DataCalc> dataCalc = new List<DataCalc>();

        Debug.WriteLine("So the center is on [{0}]/[{1}]", centerPosition.Latitude, centerPosition.Longitude);

        foreach (Position pos in farestPosition)
        {
            dataCalc.Add(new DataCalc()
            {
                Pos = pos,
                Distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pos.Latitude - centerPosition.Latitude, 2) + Math.Pow(pos.Longitude - centerPosition.Longitude, 2))
            });
        }

        DataCalc First = new DataCalc() { Distance = 0 };
        foreach (DataCalc dc in dataCalc)
        {
            if (dc.Distance > First.Distance)
            {
                First = dc;
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("The farest one is on [{0}]/[{1}]", First.Pos.Latitude, First.Pos.Longitude);

        DataCalc Second = new DataCalc() { Distance = 0 };
        foreach (DataCalc dc in dataCalc)
        {
            if (dc.Distance > Second.Distance
                && (dc.Pos.Latitude != First.Pos.Latitude && dc.Pos.Longitude != First.Pos.Longitude))
            {
                Second = dc;
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("the second is on [{0}]/[{1}]", Second.Pos.Latitude, Second.Pos.Longitude);

        FarestPos[0] = First.Pos;
        FarestPos[1] = Second.Pos;

        return (FarestPos);
    }
    public class CameraFocusData
    {
        public Position Position { get; set; }
        public Distance Distance { get; set; }
    }

    //HAVERSINE
    public static CameraFocusData GetPositionAndZoomLevelForCameraAboutPositions(Position[] FarestPoints)
    {
        double earthRadius = 6371000; //metros

        Position pos1 = FarestPoints[0];
        Position pos2 = FarestPoints[1];

        double latitud1Radianes = pos1.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        double latitud2Radianes = pos2.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        double longitud1Radianes = pos2.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        double longitud2Radianes = pos2.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);

        double deltaLatitud = (pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude) * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        double deltaLongitud = (pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude) * (Math.PI / 180.0);

        double sum1 = Math.Sin(deltaLatitud / 2) * Math.Sin(deltaLatitud / 2);
        double sum2 = Math.Cos(latitud1Radianes) * Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) * Math.Sin(deltaLongitud / 2) * Math.Sin(deltaLongitud / 2);

        var a = sum1 + sum2;
        var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));

        var distance = earthRadius * c;

        /* lt is deltaLatitud
         * lng is deltaLongitud*/
        var Bx = Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) * Math.Cos(deltaLongitud);
        var By = Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) * Math.Sin(deltaLongitud);
        var lt = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(latitud1Radianes) + Math.Sin(latitud2Radianes),
                            Math.Sqrt((Math.Cos(latitud1Radianes) + Bx) * (Math.Cos(latitud2Radianes) + Bx) + By * By));//Latitud del punto medio
        var lng = longitud1Radianes + Math.Atan2(By, Math.Cos(longitud1Radianes) + Bx);//Longitud del punto medio

        Debug.WriteLine("the final pos of the camera is on [{0}]/[{1}]", lt, lng);

        return (new CameraFocusData() { Position = new Position(lt, lng), Distance = new Distance(distance + 0.2) });
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I then found the solution, there is the code for it, it has been wrote to be put into your custom map.

Here, `private static void OnCustomPinsPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)` is a method which is called by my `List<CustomPins>` but you can use a different method.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CustomPinsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomPins), typeof(IList<CustomPin>), typeof(CustomMap), null,
            propertyChanged: OnCustomPinsPropertyChanged);
```

Also, you can add the lat/long of the user, I didn't do it because of my needs which are without the pos of the user :).

Finaly, you can add a multiplicator for the zoom, I mean, you could say, hmm, the zoom is to far for me, then ok, do like me and multiplicate the `double distance` value by something as `0.7` or `0.6` :)

```
    #region Camera focus definition
    public class CameraFocusData
    {
        public Position Position { get; set; }
        public Distance Distance { get; set; }
    }
    private static void OnCustomPinsPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        CustomMap customMap = ((CustomMap)bindable);

        if (customMap.CameraFocusParameter == CameraFocusReference.OnPins)
        {
            List<double> latitudes = new List<double>();
            List<double> longitudes = new List<double>();

            foreach (CustomPin pin in (newValue as List<CustomPin>))
            {
                latitudes.Add(pin.Position.Latitude);
                longitudes.Add(pin.Position.Longitude);
            }

            double lowestLat = latitudes.Min();
            double highestLat = latitudes.Max();
            double lowestLong = longitudes.Min();
            double highestLong = longitudes.Max();
            double finalLat = (lowestLat + highestLat) / 2;
            double finalLong = (lowestLong + highestLong) / 2;

            double distance = DistanceCalculation.GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(lowestLat, lowestLong, highestLat, highestLong, DistanceCalculation.GeoCodeCalcMeasurement.Kilometers);

            customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(finalLat, finalLong), Distance.FromKilometers(distance * 0.7)));
        }
    }
    private class DistanceCalculation
    {
        public static class GeoCodeCalc
        {
            public const double EarthRadiusInMiles = 3956.0;
            public const double EarthRadiusInKilometers = 6367.0;

            public static double ToRadian(double val) { return val * (Math.PI / 180); }
            public static double DiffRadian(double val1, double val2) { return ToRadian(val2) - ToRadian(val1); }

            public static double CalcDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
            {
                return CalcDistance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, GeoCodeCalcMeasurement.Miles);
            }

            public static double CalcDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2, GeoCodeCalcMeasurement m)
            {
                double radius = GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInMiles;

                if (m == GeoCodeCalcMeasurement.Kilometers) { radius = GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInKilometers; }
                return radius * 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(Math.Sin((DiffRadian(lat1, lat2)) / 2.0), 2.0) + Math.Cos(ToRadian(lat1)) * Math.Cos(ToRadian(lat2)) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin((DiffRadian(lng1, lng2)) / 2.0), 2.0)))));
            }
        }

        public enum GeoCodeCalcMeasurement : int
        {
            Miles = 0,
            Kilometers = 1
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Have fun !

---

### UPDATE of DEC 2018

**I worked on a solution which I hosted a long time ago on my repo, with the other POCs https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/Map/MapPinsProject**

Comment: answer updated :) once you see this message, please remove yours as I did, so the answer stays clean :)