# How to set auto zoom & auto center according to latitude longitude without fitBounds?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, google-maps

Here is my code, I want to fit autozoom and center according to the marker position on map such that each and every marker would visble on minimum possible zoom

```
var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $latitude; ?>', '<?php echo $longitude; ?>'),  
                    zoom: 12,
                      scrollwheel: false,
                      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: why u dnt want to use fitBounds ..?? method..??

Comment: There are no markers in the posted code.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically adjust zoom to accommodate all marker in a google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897744/automatically-adjust-zoom-to-accommodate-all-marker-in-a-google-map)

Comment: i am using fitBounds but not working in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help.

```
var zoom = 12;
              var lat1 = '<?php echo $first_lat; ?>';
              var lat2 = '<?php echo $latitude; ?>';
              var lon1 = '<?php echo $first_lng; ?>';
              var lon2 = '<?php echo $longitude; ?>';
              var unit = 'M';



            function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
      var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
      var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
      var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
      var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
      var theta = lon1-lon2
      var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
      var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
      dist = Math.acos(dist)
      dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
      if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
      if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
      return dist
     }
     var dis = distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit);

      // change value according to your needs.

       if (dis > '2.0' && dis < '3.9'){   
            zoom = 11

           } else if (dis > '4.0' && dis < '5.9'){
            zoom = 10;

           } else if (dis > '6.0' && dis < '9.9'){
            zoom = 9;

           } else if (dis > '10.0'){
            zoom = 8;

           } 



    var mapOptions = {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lon1),   
                 zoom: zoom,
                   scrollwheel: false,
       disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             };
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
             {
      /*
       FOLLOW YOUR OTHER MAP CODE <../> 
       */

              }
```

Thanks